# Last Nonzero Digits of a Factorial in Base

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, base-conversion, restricted-time, factorial

You should write a program or function which given three positive integers `n b k` as input outputs or returns the last `k` digits before the trailing zeros in the base `b` representation of `n!`.

### Example

```
n=7 b=5 k=4
factorial(n) is 5040
5040 is 130130 in base 5
the last 4 digits of 130130 before the trailing zeros are 3013
the output is 3013
```

### Input

- 3 positive integers `n b k` where `2 <= b <= 10`.
- The order of the input integers can be chosen arbitrarily.

### Output

- A list of digits returned or outputted as an integer or integer list.
- Leading zeros are optional.
- **Your solution has to solve any example test case under a minute** on my computer (I will only test close cases. I have a below-average PC.).

### Examples

*New tests added to check correctness of submissions. (They are not part of the under 1 minute runtime rule.)*

Input => Output (with the choice of omitting leading zeros)

```
3 10 1  =>  6

7 5 4  =>  3013

3 2 3  =>  11

6 2 10  =>  101101

9 9 6  =>  6127

7 10 4  =>  504

758 9 19  =>  6645002302217537863

158596 8 20  =>  37212476700442254614

359221 2 40  =>  1101111111001100010101100000110001110001

New tests:
----------

9 6 3  =>  144

10 6 3  =>  544
```

This is code-golf, so the shortest entry wins.

Comment: *under a minute on my computer* is a little difficult to aim for if we don't know any specifics.

Comment: Would `7 5 3` output "013" or "13"?

Comment: @Claudiu based on the `7 10 4` test case I would say `13`

Comment: @Claudiu "Leading zeros are optional." so both version is correct.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the algorithm necessary. Can someone help explain? I'm looking here, but it's a bit different since there's a change of base: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/71768.html

Comment: If we choose integer list for output, does endianness matter?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, endianness matters. I used the 1 min rule to clearly separate the simple O(n^2) algorithms from the rest but that might have been a failed attempt.

Comment: wont you settle a score-meter for this ?

Comment: Is a list of integers as output OK, or is a string required?

Comment: @isaacg It is ok. "A list of digits returned or outputted as an integer or integer list."  (just edited the `,` to `or`).

Comment: Do you have bounds for n?

Comment: Must we accept *any* positive integer for `n` or `k`?  Or can we limit them to the range of the language's integer type?

Comment: @TobySpeight Your integer type can limit the range where you can solve the problem but the given should cause no problem for your code.

Comment: Are you going to change the accepted answer with the renewed interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 23 bytes

```
⌽k↑⌽{⍵↓⍨-⊥⍨0=⍵}b⊥⍣¯1⊢!n
```

This program works as long as the factorial does not exceed internal representation limit. In Dyalog APL, the limit can be raised by `⎕FR←1287`.

Assumes the variables n, b, and k have been set (e.g. `n b k←7 5 4`), but if you rather want prompting for *n*, *b*, and *k* (in that order) then replace the three characters with `⎕`.

Comment: Every test case I threw at it was computed in about 11 microseconds on my machine (M540).

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, <s>57</s> 48 bytes

Saved 9 bytes thanks to @2012rcampion .

```
IntegerString[#!/#2^#!~IntegerExponent~#2,##2]&
```

Comment: I've never really used mathematica, but couldn't you swap the order of the arguments to make `b` first to save 2 bytes?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I'm new to the golfing community, is swapping argument order "kosher"?

Comment: You can actually get to 47: `IntegerString[#!#2^-#!~IntegerExponent~#2,##2]&` (both this and your original are quite fast)

Comment: The asker wrote: "The order of the input integers can be chosen arbitrarily." under input, so in this case it's definitely fine

Comment: @Fry Wow, looks like I didn't read closely enough.  However, the `SlotSequence` trick I used in my comment only works with the current order, so you couldn't save any more.

Answer (score 7):

### Python, <strike>198</strike> <strike>192</strike> 181 chars

```
def F(n,b,k):
 p=5820556928/8**b%8;z=0;e=f=x=1
 while n/p**e:z+=n/p**e;e+=1
 z/=1791568/4**b%4;B=b**(z+k)
 while x<=n:f=f*x%B;x+=1
 s='';f/=b**z
 while f:s=str(f%b)+s;f/=b
 return s
```

It's fast enough, ~23 seconds on the biggest example.  And no factorial builtin (I'm looking at you, Mathematica!).

Comment: `[2,3,2,5,3,7,2,3,5][b-2]` could be `int('232537235'[b-2])` to save 3 bytes. `[1,1,2,1,1,1,3,2,1][b-2]` similarly.

Comment: For the latter, a lookup table `111973>>2*(b-2)&3` is even shorter. It's the same number of bytes for the former though (`90946202>>3*(b-2)&7`).

Comment: nvm looks like you were right about the higher digits thing

Comment: I believe you can save a few bytes by making this a program and not a function.

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>26</s> 35 bytes

```
M?G%GHg/GHH.N>ju%g*GhHT^T+YslNN1T_Y
```

This is a function of 3 arguments, number, base, number of digits.

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=M%3FG%25GHg%2FGHH.N%3Eju%25g*GhHT%5ET%2BYslNN1T_Y%3A9+6+3&debug=0)

The slowest test case, the final one, takes 15 seconds on my machine.

Comment: @Sp3000 I added a fix which I think should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

### PARI/GP, 43 bytes

Trading speed for space yields this straightforward algorithm:

```
(n,b,k)->digits(n!/b^valuation(n!,b)%b^k,b)
```

Each of the test cases runs in less than a second on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>111</s> 109 bytes

```
import Data.Digits
f n b k=digits b$foldl(((unDigits b.reverse.take k.snd.span(<1).digitsRev b).).(*))1[1..n]
```

Usage: `f 158596 8 20` -> `[3,7,2,1,2,4,7,6,7,0,0,4,4,2,2,5,4,6,1,4]`

Takes about 8 seconds for `f 359221 2 40` on my 4 year old laptop.

How it works: fold the multiplication (`*`) into the list `[1..n]`. Convert every intermediate result to base `b` as a list of digits (least significant first), strip leading zeros, then take the first `k` digits and convert to base 10 again. Finally convert to base `b` again, but with most significant digit first.

Comment: you had the idea in my mind , that i was interpreting it using matlab , what a coincidende :D

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 146 bytes

```python
import math
i,f=input(),int
n=i.split()
e=math.factorial(f(n[0]))
d=''
while e>0:
 d=str((e%f(n[1])))+d;e=e//f(n[1])
print(d.strip('0')[-f(n[2]):])
```

I'm not sure the test cases will all run fast enough - the larger ones are very slow (as it is looping through the number).

Try it online [here](http://repl.it/lsT) (but be careful).

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>303</s> <s>299</s> 296 bytes

```
import java.math.*;interface R{static void main(String[]a){BigInteger c=new BigInteger(a[1]),b=c.valueOf(1);for(int i=new Integer(a[0]);i>0;i--){b=b.multiply(b.valueOf(i));while(b.mod(c).equals(b.ZERO))b=b.divide(c);b=b.mod(c.pow(new Integer(a[2])));}System.out.print(b.toString(c.intValue()));}}
```

On my computer, this averages a little under a third of a second on the `359221 2 40` testcase. Takes input via command line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

## bc, 75 bytes

```
define void f(n,b,k){
obase=b
for(x=1;n;x%=b^k){
x*=n--
while(!x%b)x/=b}
x}
```

This uses some GNU extensions to reduce code size; a POSIX-conforming equivalent weighs in at 80 bytes:

```
define f(n,b,k){
obase=b
for(x=1;n;x%=b^k){
x*=n--
while(x%b==0)x/=b}
return(x)}
```

To keep run times reasonable, we trim the trailing zeros (`while(!x%b)x/=b`) and truncate to the final `k` digits (`x%=b^k`) as we compute the factorial (`for(x=1;n;)x*=n--`).

#### Test program:

```
f(3, 10, 1)
f(7, 5, 4)
f(3, 2, 3)
f(6, 2, 10)
f(9, 9, 6)
f(7, 10, 4)
f(758, 9, 19)
f(158596, 8, 20)
f(359221, 2, 40)
f(9, 6, 3)
f(10, 6, 3)
quit
```

Runtime of the full test suite is approx 4¼ seconds on my 2006-vintage workstation.

Comment: This is my first ever `bc` program (golf or not), so any tips are especially welcome...

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 80 bytes

```
function f($a,$b,$c){echo substr(rtrim(gmp_strval(gmp_fact($a),$b),"0"),-1*$c);}
```

Used as  `f(359221,2,40)` for the last test case. Runs pretty smoothly for all test cases.

[Try here !](https://ideone.com/yt2zb9)